# SQL measure stored procedure execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to measure the time it take to execute a Stored Procedure in SQL Server. But instead of just measuring the entire stored procedure execution I would also like to measure the time each operation inside the stored procedure takes, so I could find bottlenecks.

In c# to accomplish such a thing when testing code execution time I would save the date before execution starts and when execution ends I would print the TimeSpan object that is given to me by subtracting the start time from the current time (after execution).

I was wondering how I could achieve such thing with SQL Server inside a stored procedure where I could print the time span I measure between operation within the stored procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
GO

EXECUTE <yourSP>;

GO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Does that also measure executions on inserts and updates? is it recommended for production on just development?

Comment: It measures everything and is safe for production use - for troubleshooting

Comment: After executing above where the time required to execute stored procedure will be shown?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was the suggestion posted here:
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1151457/a-simple-method-to-measure-execution-time-in-sql-s

```
Declare @StartTime DateTime2

SET @StartTime = SysUTCDateTime()

-- SQL Execution

Print 'Time taken was ' + cast(DateDiff(millisecond, @StartTime, SysUTCDateTime()) as varchar) + 'ms'

SET @StartTime = SysUTCDateTime()

-- Second SQL Execution

Print 'Time taken was ' + cast(DateDiff(millisecond, @StartTime, SysUTCDateTime()) as varchar) + 'ms'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [actual execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/). You can see these from running the SQL query in SQL Management studio with the right button pressed (they'll appear as a tab in the results window). This will show you what parts of the sproc is being run and the time taken up by each bit - just what you want to tune.